# Is MSc the same as MSc (Eng)?

Tags: united-kingdom, titles

I have a master's degree in the UK, titled MSc Advanced Materials Engineering.

I would like to know if it would be correct to put MSc (Eng) as a post-nominal?

There is no clear guidance. By using just MSc in a post-nominal it is of course not implicit that the qualification is in an engineering subject. I would like to make that distinction if it is permitted to do so.

Comment: In some places, engineers are required to add "Eng" to their names when signing professional documents. Wheres, you can hold your "MSc Advanced Materials Engineering"  while not holding a bachelor of engineering degree. Hence, it could be perceived as deceiving to add "(Eng)" to your title if indeed you are not an engineer.

Comment: If it helps, I also have a BEng (Hons).

Comment: That's means my comment is not a concern for you, it could be for other people. For example, I know many physicists who later pursued masters or PhDs in engineering.

Answer (score 3):

You hold an *MSc*, not an *MSc (Eng)*, so use the former.

If you want the reader to know you have an engineering degree, then write *MSc Advanced Materials Engineering*, perhaps even *MSc, Engineering dept., Uni X* for something shorter.

Note that *MEng* also exists, so *MSc (Eng)* may baffle some.

Answer (score 2):

A UK university will tell you what is the correct abbreviation for your degree. The commenters above who profess ignorance of the abbreviation MSc(Eng) show their youth. The year before I took my MSc at Imperial College London, the same course would have led to a degree officially abbreviated as MSc(Eng).

Nobody is at all interested in how your degree is abbreviated, however. What they want to know is how well qualified you are for what it is you say you want to do. In some contexts your degree (however it is abbreviated) will be relevant to some professional status, such as certified engineer, but that will depend on detailed specific regulations and not on how you choose to describe your qualifications.

Answer (score 1):

+: As long as you can back it up when someone asks you, it is fine. You are not cheating by adding parentheses.

-: MSc (Eng) looks confusing at least to me.

I would say if possible, write the degree in full rather than using abbreviations. Otherwise, maybe provide some context on why and where you need to use short alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

MSc(Eng), aka MScEng, is an abbreviation for [Master of Science in Engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_of_Science_in_Engineering).

The answer depends on the full name displayed on your degree certificate. The question itself contains an abbreviation (*MSc Advanced Materials Engineering*) so it's hard to say conclusively.

If your full degree name is: *Master of Science: Advanced Materials Engineering*, then the precise abbreviation would simply be `MSc`.

If on the other hand, the full degree name is *Master of Science in Engineering: Advanced Materials Engineering*, then it would be accurate to use the `MSc(Eng)` abbreviation.

**Additional Background**

The Master of Science in Engineering is always a postgraduate degree. In contrast, a Master of Engineering degree (MEng) can sometimes be considered an undergraduate degree. Some universities offer a one year MEng degree on top of a 3-year Bachelor of Engineering (BEng), or an integrated [four-year MEng degree](https://www.southampton.ac.uk/courses/mechanical-engineering-degree-meng). This makes it equivalent to a four-year Bachelor of Science in Engineering, abbreviated as BSc(Eng) or BSE. See for example the [BScEng degree at GCU](https://www.gcu.edu/degree-programs/bachelor-science-engineering), or the [BScEng degree at Wits](https://www.wits.ac.za/course-finder/undergraduate/ebe/mechanical-engineering/), both requiring four years of study.

A Master of Science in Engineering can sometimes be done purely by research, or a combination of research and coursework. See for example, the [MScEng in Electrical Engineering at UCT](https://ebe.uct.ac.za/department-electrical-engineering/postgraduate-programmes/master-science-engineering-specialising-electrical-engineering).

Some universities also used to offer five-year engineering Bachelor degrees, which in my understanding is recognized by the [Bologna Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bologna_Process) as being equivalent to an MEng degree. MIT also had a [five-year MEng degree program](https://www.eecs.mit.edu/about/departmental-history/):

> In 1993, it established a five-year Master of Engineering (MEng)
> program, under which MIT undergraduates stay for a fifth year and
> receive simultaneous bachelor’s (SB) and master’s of engineering
> (MEng) degrees.

**Conclusion**

Different universities offer different degrees, with different names, which can be confusing. The main point to remember is that MScEng is a postgraduate degree and an abbreviation for Master of Science in Engineering. If that's what your degree says, MScEng, MSc(Eng) or [MSE](https://name.engin.umich.edu/home/academics/graduate-studies/mse-degree/) are valid abbreviations.

Answer (score 0):

MSc is a degree *classification* (Master of Science) referring to a specialisation in the field of natural sciences (compare to BSc as a general degree or MA - Master of Arts for Humanities). MEng, on the other hand, is a degree *name* (Mechanichal Engineering). Certain common abbreviations may be allowed, such as MBA (Master's in Business Administration). MSc (Eng) is meaningless to me, I would advise against it and there is a clear distinction between the abbreviations. For someone unaware of the differences, *Eng* might even stand for English.

Comment: MEng isn't a degree name, it's a degree classification: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_of_Engineering

Comment: I have seen it used in both contexts.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't _MEng Mechanical Engineering_? (Which is common.)

Comment: The one I am most familiar with is MSc Mechanical Engineering, or MSc MEng if an abbreviation is needed. I have seen your example as MEng (Mechanical Engineering).

Comment: I've never seen it; thanks for educating me.

Comment: https://www.ucl.ac.uk/prospective-students/graduate/taught-degrees/mechanical-engineering-msc and https://www.lboro.ac.uk/study/postgraduate/masters-degrees/a-z/mechanical-engineering/, from Google's first page.

Comment: Neither of those pages contain MEng. (Well, the former does, but only in an email address.)

Comment: MEng refers to an integrated master's degree. See my explanation in the question comments.